# how to create frontend controller and action in gocart

Tags: php, codeigniter, controller

I am facing some problems in gocart codeigniter. I create a front end controller named **decorate**
then action named **products** and passing slug in action.

Following is the code of controller

```
<?php

class Decorate extends Front_Controller {

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        //make sure we're not always behind ssl
        remove_ssl();

        $this->load->model(array('Decorate_model'));
        $this->lang->load('decorate');
    }

    function index()
    {
        $data['page_title'] = lang('decorates');

        $data['decorates']  = $this->Decorate_model->get_front_all_decorates();

        $this->load->view('decorate_home',$data);
    }

    /* Single Decorate */   

    function products($decorate_slug)
    {
        $data['page_title'] = lang('decorates');
    }
}

?>
```

But when I am running url `www.abc.com/gocart/index.php/decorate/products/decorate-1`

then it is showing 404 error. I am not getting how to create action in gocart.

Comment: You have not view in `products` function. Add `$this->index();` after your action codes

Comment: I am just checking it whether will it work or not.If I use any view then also its not working

Comment: Add `$this->load->view('decorate_home');` to `products` function. Do you get error again?

Answer (score 0):

Could be Gocart routes everything to one master controller. What's in your routes.php?